# Parsing dates correctly using read_excel in R

Tags: r, date, parsing, lubridate, readxl

I am trying to read the excel file using read_excel function in R. I read using the following function

```
dat <- read_excel(path = "testing.xlsx", sheet = "Social Media") %>% select(name:date)
```

The `dput` of the data frame is as follows:

```
dat <- structure(list(name = c("JOhn", "Ramesh", "Amir", "Priyanka", 
"Scott", "Lance", "Robert", "Clement", "Fang", "Xing"), platform = c("Facebook", 
"Twitter", "Twitter", "Twitter", "Twitter", "Twitter", "Twitter", 
"Facebook", "Twitter", "Twitter"), date = c("44168", "14/03/2020", 
"16/3/2020", "15/03/2020", "14/03/2020", "14/03/2020", "16/03/2020", 
"14/03/2020", "44168", "13/03/2020")), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

As you can see that dates are parsed as decimal and string. I want to parse everything to the same format.

The data I am reading from excel is as follows:

[image]

The file can be downloaded from https://easyupload.io/itsbxy

This is what I am doing in R.

```
dat <- dat %>% 
    mutate(date1 = lubridate::parse_date_time(date, c('dmY'))) 
dat$date1[is.na(dat$date1)] <- as.Date(as.numeric(dat$date[is.na(dat$date1)]), origin = "1899-12-30", )

The output is as follows; 
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   name     platform date       date1              
   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>      <dttm>             
 1 JOhn     Facebook 44168      2020-12-03 00:00:00
 2 Ramesh   Twitter  14/03/2020 2020-03-14 00:00:00
 3 Amir     Twitter  16/3/2020  2020-03-16 00:00:00
 4 Priyanka Twitter  15/03/2020 2020-03-15 00:00:00
 5 Scott    Twitter  14/03/2020 2020-03-14 00:00:00
 6 Lance    Twitter  14/03/2020 2020-03-14 00:00:00
 7 Robert   Twitter  16/03/2020 2020-03-16 00:00:00
 8 Clement  Facebook 14/03/2020 2020-03-14 00:00:00
 9 Fang     Twitter  44168      2020-12-03 00:00:00
10 Xing     Twitter  13/03/2020 2020-03-13 00:00:00
```

This way I parsed all the dates but the dates that were read as decimal were converted to different format.

How do I fix this issue ? First and second last dates should have been 2020-03-12 and 2020-03-12

Comment: The data in your Excel screenshot is clearly in different formats. Suggesting you start with a consistent data source before reading into R.

Comment: This is the data I get in raw format. How can I fix it within R?

Comment: Your problem comes before you read the data into R. Excel value for 2020-03-12 is 43902. In your `dput` it is 44168. You can modify your code to `origin = "1899-04-08"` if you want a quick and very, very dirty fix - but I really don't think that's a good idea.